# I cannot set dynamic size for UICollectionView

Tags: uicollectionview

I want to set UICollectionView's height according to it's contents height. And I dont want to scroll it.

```
 @property(nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint* containerHeight;

 _containerHeight.constant = musicStoreViewController.collectionView.contentSize.height;
```

This causes exception

```
 [__NSCFType collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:]
```

What can I do?

Comment: where does "`_containerHeight`" come from?  Your solution is going to involve doing some work with the "`UICollectionViewLayout`" class.